# Bank account deposit option using text file in C

Tags: c, file, edit

I'm trying to make a simple bank program and I'm trying to get the deposit part to work, I'm using a text file to store information such as Account number, account holder first and last name and the balance in the account.

I'm trying to do here is to get the user to enter an account number which then the program will open the existing file called Bank.txt and check if there is a matching account number. if there is the program will then proceed to ask the user to enter the value to deposit, and if not then the program will simply tell the user that the account number doesn’t exist.

The problem I have is when I first run the program and create an account everything runs fine but as soon as I close the program and reopen it, it doesn’t find the matching account number in the file even though it already exists.

Full code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 10 000
#define NAME_LEN 60
#define MAX_ACCOUNT 1000

struct bank
{
    int account_number;
    char first_name[NAME_LEN+1];
    char last_name[NAME_LEN+1];
    float accountBalance;
} enter;

void create();
/*void searchAccounts();
void viewAccounts();
void sortAccounts();
void withdraw();
void deposit();
void Account_Balance();
void Account_eliminate();
*/
int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    while(1)
        {
            printf("\t\t\t      Welcome to KTH Elektro Bank! \n \t\t     Please select your options form the menu below 1-9\n\n");
            printf("\t\t 1 : Create Account\n");
            printf("\t\t 2 : Search Accounts\n");
            printf("\t\t 3 : View Accounts\n");
            printf("\t\t 4 : Sort Accounts\n");
            printf("\t\t 5 : Deposit \n");
            printf("\t\t 6 : Withdraw \n");
            printf("\t\t 7 : Check Balance \n");
            printf("\t\t 8 : Delete Account \n");
            printf("\t\t 9 : Exit \n\n");
            printf("\t\t please enter choice : ");
            scanf("%d", &ch);
            switch(ch)
            {
               case 1: create();
                        break;
            /*  case 2: searchAccounts();
                        break;
                case 3: viewAccounts();
                        break;
                case 4: sortAccounts();
                        break;*/
                case 5: deposit();
                        break;/*
                case 6: withdraw();
                        break;
                case 7: Account_Balance();
                        break;
                case 8: Account_eliminate();
                        break;*/
                case 9: exit(0);
                        default: printf("\t\tEnter 1-9 Only");
                        getch();
            }
        }
}

void create()
{
    FILE *originalFile = fopen("Bank.txt","w");
    printf("\n\t\t Account Creation Page\n");
    printf("\t\t Enter Desired Account Number Minimum 6 Digits! : ");
        scanf("%d", &enter.account_number);
    printf("\t\t Enter Your First Name : ");
        scanf("%s",  enter.first_name);
    printf("\t\t Enter Your Last Name : ");
        scanf("%s",  enter.last_name);
    printf("\t\t Your balance is by default set to 0 KR \n\n");
        enter.accountBalance = 0;
    fprintf(originalFile,"\n Account Number : %d \n First Name : %s \n Last Name : %s \n Balance : %f", enter.account_number,enter.first_name, enter.last_name, enter.accountBalance);
    fclose(originalFile);
    getch();
}

void deposit()
{
    printf("\n\t\t Deposit Page\n");

    int acc_no;
    printf("\t\t Enter The Account Number of the Account \n\t\t You Would Like To Deposit To : ");
    scanf("%d", &acc_no);

    FILE *originalFile = fopen("Bank.txt", "r");
    FILE *newFile = fopen("BankTemp.txt", "w");
    fscanf(originalFile, "Account Number : %d", enter.account_number);
    fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder First Name : %s", enter.first_name);
    fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder Last Nam : %s", enter.last_name);
    fscanf(originalFile, "Balance : %f", enter.accountBalance);

    if (acc_no == enter.account_number)
    {
        float balance;
        printf("\n\t\t Enter The Amount You Would Like To Deposit : ");
        scanf("%f", &balance);
        enter.accountBalance = balance + enter.accountBalance;
        fprintf(newFile, "\n Account Number : %d \n First Name : %s \n Last Name : %s \n Balance : %f", enter.account_number, enter.first_name, enter.last_name, enter.accountBalance);
        fclose(newFile);
        fclose(originalFile);
        remove("Bank.txt");
        rename("BankTemp.txt", "Bank.txt");
    }

    if(acc_no != enter.account_number)
    {
        printf("\t\t Account Number Doesn't Exist\n");
        fclose(originalFile);
        fclose(newFile);
        remove("BankTemp.txt");
    }

}
```

Comment: Add lots of logging output to your program so that you can see where it's going wrong. Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

From man `scanf`, but `fscanf()` works similarly, about what to read when a character is specified in the format string:

> An ordinary character (i.e., one other than white space or '%').  This character must exactly match the next character of input.

when you do for example:

```
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder First Name : %s", enter.first_name);
```

you do not have this exact text in the file, you wrote something like `"First Name : %s \n"`. And that will not match.

Also, if the user name have some space in it that code will not work as expected. My advice would be to simplify the format, maybe by writing one datum on each line. Then read whole lines with `fgets()` and parse the line, if needed, with `scanf()`.

On more serious projects you may want to consider using a proper database, or even sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

From comments and answers there are probably severals bugs in your program *("there's always one more bug!")*. Mine is that I can't see any "append" mode when updating the file. In `create()` you have

```
FILE *originalFile = fopen("Bank.txt","w");
```

This will destroy the file you already have. In `deposit()` You make a new file with a single customer, you then delete the file you had, and rename the new one. It might be better to add a record with

```
FILE *originalFile = fopen("Bank.txt","a");
```

But I would not even do that. I would have one file for each customer, named by its account, say `10042.txt`. If the customer does not know the account number, you could then search each file for the name (and PIN?).

Comment: You should better have another file that links customers and their accounts/file names (Like a dictionary) in case you have lot of accounts it will be faster than opening each file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the references in the following lines:

```
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Number : %d", enter.account_number);
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder First Name : %s", enter.first_name);
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder Last Nam : %s", enter.last_name);
fscanf(originalFile, "Balance : %f", enter.accountBalance);
```

so that they read:

```
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Number : %d", &enter.account_number);
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder First Name : %s", enter.first_name);
fscanf(originalFile, "Account Holder Last Nam : %s", enter.last_name);
fscanf(originalFile, "Balance : %f", &enter.accountBalance);
```